# Angular POST response headers

Tags: angularjs

I wish to get my response headers. I've done response transform when using $resource and yet it only gives me: application/json,charset=utf_8

Yes, my backend has all the needed CORS header related stuff (both allow and expose).

I've tried $http with a success(data, status, headers, config)
but when i console.log(headers()) it's undefined.

Help?

Comment: Which header would you like to get. What is the actual code you tried? What does the browser dev tools network panel say about the response headers?

Comment: headers is an object, not a function. Try `console.log(headers)`.